# Converting string array to multidimensional double

Tags: c#, windows

I need to read a matrix from a file in to double[,]. Till now it is possible to read the file as a string[]. The datastructure looks like that:
[image]

But the conversion doesn't work.

I already tried a lot of stackoverflow articles, but it failed always with "Input string was not in a correct format". Important is that the values are all double values and seperated with three spaces.

I read the file like this:

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines(@"right.txt");
```

Comment: How are you doing the conversion? Where's your code for that? You should be using `double.Parse()` on each representative string. If you don't post your code, we don't know why it doesn't work. And there's no point in us repeating what you've read in the articles again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this several ways, and it depends if you want a jagged array, or a multidimensional array.

There are probably more succinct ways of doing this, however, you can see the idea.

**Jagged**

```
var jaggedArray = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\right.txt")
                        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                        .Select(x => x.Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                     .Select(double.Parse)
                                     .ToArray())
                        .ToArray();
```

**Multidimensional**

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\right.txt")
                  .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                  .Select(x => x.Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                               .Select(double.Parse)
                               .ToList())
                  .ToList();

var h = lines.Count();
var w = lines.Max(x => x.Count);
var multiArray = new double[h, w];

for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
   for (var j = 0; j < lines[i].Count; j++)
      multiArray[i, j] = lines[i][j];
```

<sub>***Note***: Totally untested, and I am not responsible for the people maim or otherwise harm with this code</sub>
<sub>***Note 2***: There is no error checking or fault tolerance, if there is garbage in your file, this will likely throw</sub>

**Update**

> Is there a way to debug/fix that? Maybe the problem is that the double
>   values are separated with 3 spaces and not only 1 space? Is there a
>   way to fix this in a LINQ statement?

Yes if there are multiple spaces using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` should work

```
Split(new [] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

However note, this really assumes, that every separated value can be converted to a `double`, and there is no blank lines (even at the end of the file)

You can solve the blank line problem by using something like this included in the *linq* statement

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"right.txt")
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    ...
```

Comment: The multidimensional way seems good but it doesn't work for me. I get an exception in the LINQ statement. `System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'` Is there a way to debug/fix that? Maybe the problem is that the double values are separated with 3 spaces and not only 1 space? Is there a way to fix this in a LINQ statement?

Comment: thanks, but `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))`doesn't work. I got through with the debugger, multiple spaces still present in the string.

Comment: @Sabina that line deals with blank lines the split option deals with multiple spaces. are you sure they are spaces and not tabs or something?\

Comment: You can be sure by `Split(new [] {' ',\t'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Also lets not guess any further can put your sample data on the question, or link to a file online, as this could go on all day

Comment: Yes that is easier: https://ufile.io/gtgxw
I already tried the other solution with RemoveEmptyEntries, but doesn't work either.

Comment: @Sabina small typo, they both now work with your file

Comment: no exception :-) but multarray has only integers and no double values? (the values are correct but 0. is missing in front of the number)